# Infinite recursive call

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-8

Hi I recently back to Java after a decade in Scala.

I create a Kafka consumer that have to poll records constantly, so in order to do that I create an infinite recursive call. But now I remember that in Scala we have `tail recursion`, but we dont in Java right?

Here the code

```
private void consumeRecords(final Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer, String topic) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(ofMillis(1000));
        consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            logger.info("[{}] new events:", topic);
            logger.info("Record Key {}", record.key());
            logger.info("Record value {}", new String(record.value()));
            logger.info("Record partition {}", record.partition());
            logger.info("Record offset {}", record.offset());
        });
        consumer.commitAsync();
        consumeRecords(consumer, topic);
    }
```

I guess is better just use a `while(true)` right?

```
private void consumeRecords(final Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer, String topic) {
    while(true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(ofMillis(1000));
        consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
            logger.info("[{}] new events:", topic);
            logger.info("Record Key {}", record.key());
            logger.info("Record value {}", new String(record.value()));
            logger.info("Record partition {}", record.partition());
            logger.info("Record offset {}", record.offset());
        });
        consumer.commitAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, yes you are right - some JVM languages do support Tail Call Optimization, but Java does not.

Comment: oh yes, it does thanks guys!